# XHTML/CSS 3 Column Quandry

Tags: html, css

I am new to the world of coding, XHTML, CSS and PHP. This is my first attempt to conjure a what I *understand* to be a 3 column layout based on my minimal knowledge of CSS.

What I am confused about is using `overflow: auto` as well as structuring the document.

For example, I was reading the tutorial at http://www.icms.info/website-howto/css-tutorial which I believe to be convoluted. I hence created a 3 column layout based on what I knew. I changed the position of the content div tag just above the footer div tag as opposed to it appearing above navigation. My confusion hence is

**Question 1**

Why did I have to change the position of my content div tag from (as the article suggests that the content div tag be above the navigation div tag)?

```
   <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            header
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            content
        </div>

        <div id="navigation">
            navigation
        </div>

        <div id="news">
            news
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            footer
        </div>
    </div>
```

to

```
 <div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        header
    </div>

    <div id="navigation">
        navigation
    </div>

    <div id="news">
        news
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        content
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        footer
    </div>
</div>
```

**Question 2**

Why wasn't I able to use the declaration `overflow: auto` in the container id selector i.e

```
#container {

            width: 750px;
            margin: 0px auto;
            border: 1px dashed #000000;
            overflow: auto;

        }
```

and had to resort to `clear: both` in the footer selector?

**Entire Code**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charsetUTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us" />
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />

<meta name="MSSmartTagsPreventParsing" content="true" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="author" content="" />

<title>Sample</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="web.css" />

<style type="text/css" media="all">

    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    body {

        background-color: #eeeeee;
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: medium;

    }

    #container {

        width: 750px;
        margin: 0px auto;
        border: 1px dashed #000000;

    }

    #header {

        height: 120px;
        background-color: gray;

    }

    #content {

        background-color: red;
        width: 715px;
        text-align: center;

    }


    #navigation {

        background-color: orange;
        float: left;

    }

    #news {

        background-color: blue;
        float: right;

    }

    #footer {

        background-color: green;
        clear: both;
    }

</style>
```

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        header
    </div>

    <div id="navigation">
        navigation
    </div>

    <div id="news">
        news
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        content
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        footer
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

@Phil.Wheeler This is what I started with;

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtm1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charsetUTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us" />
    <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />

    <meta name="MSSmartTagsPreventParsing" content="true" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />

    <title>Sample</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="web.css" />

    <style type="text/css" media="all">

        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        body {

            background-color: #eeeeee;
            font-family: arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: medium;

        }

        #container {

            width: 750px;
            margin: 0px auto;
            border: 1px dashed #000000;
            overflow: auto;

        }

        #header {

            height: 120px;
            background-color: gray;

        }

        #content {

            background-color: red;
            width: 715px;
            text-align: center;

        }


        #navigation {

            background-color: orange;
            float: left;

        }

        #news {

            background-color: blue;
            float: right;

        }

        #footer {

            background-color: green;
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            header
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            content
        </div>

        <div id="navigation">
            navigation
        </div>

        <div id="news">
            news
        </div>


        <div id="footer">
            footer
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what you started with versus what you were actually trying to achieve? Right now, it's difficult to understand exactly what your problem is.

Comment: @Phil.Wheeler - I have updated my question with the code I had. The problem I have is why I wasn't able to use `overflow: auto` as well as why is that I had to change the structure of my document?

Comment: Ok, but I'm still not clear on what you were actually trying to do. I understand your starting position, but what were you wanting to end up with? Why was `overflow: auto` such a priority? What was the problem or annoyance with having to move your HTML structure around?

Comment: @Phil.Wheeler - The reason I woud like to know why `overflow: auto;` didn't work is because I wanted to achieve the same result without using `clear: both`. Secondly, I would like to understand why my change in the structure made a difference i.e. got me a 3 column layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you point out in your opening sentence, you are new to coding so some of the HTML / CSS structure rules may seem a little counter-intuitive to start with.

I'll answer your second question first as it's the most direct. The use of the "overflow" property dictates to your browser how it should present any content that goes past the boundaries of the element it's contained in. For example, if you have a `<div>` element that is 100 pixels high, but your content is a full paragraph that goes well past 100 pixels:

- `overflow: visible` will show all the content as spilling out over the border of your `div`.
- `overflow: hidden` will expand the size of your `div` to contain all your content (as long as no other parent rules prevent or override this behaviour).
- `overflow: scroll` will display scroll bars so the user can scroll up and down (or left and right) within the `div`.
- `overflow: auto` will add scroll bars to the `div` only if its content exceeds its fixed size.

[Read more about the overflow property here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/overflow.html).

Regarding your three column layout, you'll find that changing your CSS rules a little and slightly modifying your HTML structure will make life much easier without necessarily needing to rely on `overflow` or `clear` properties in your styles. I'm assuming your columns are Content, Navigation and News.

Have a look at this example:

```
    <div class="leftCol">
        <h2>Left Column</h2>
        <p>Left column is 250px by default. It can be extended by applying other classes.</p>
        <ul>
            <li>List Item</li>
            <li>List Item</li>
            <li>List Item</li>
            <li>List Item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="rightCol">
        <h2>Right Column</h2>
        <p>The right column is by default 300px wide. It can be extended by applying other classes.</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Item One</li>
            <li>Item Two</li>
            <li>Item Three</li>
            <li>Item Four</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <h2>Main Content</h2>
        <p>Main Content is fully liquid. It takes all the remaining space on the line after the widths of “leftCol” and “rightCol” are taken into account. Alternatively, grids can be used to break up the main content area for fully fluid layouts.</p>
    </div>
```

Notice I position my floated columns in the order: left, right, main. My main column simply takes up whatever space is left between the two side columns. Here is the CSS to do it:

```
.leftCol{float:left;width:250px;_margin-right:-3px;}
.rightCol{float:right;width:300px;_margin-left:-3px;}
.main{display:table-cell;*display:block;width:auto;}
```

I haven't needed to use overflow or clear to achieve this and everything lays out nicely within whatever container I place these three elements in.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I am confused by what you mean by `The use of the "overflow" property dictates to your browser how it should present any content that goes past the boundaries of the element it's contained in.` if the div container does not have a height defined. It's probably the fact I am new to CSS and its rules as I find find the declaration `_margin-right:-3px;` as well as the use of `*display:block;` slightly more confusing. Is there any chance you can describe it in more detail as well as when I would use them?

Answer (score 0):

Question 1

having the navigation as high as possible is better for SEO.

Question 2

use the overflow: auto only on elements, which you actually WANT to have overflow auto.
It may be anyway a bad idea to have an overflow: auto, because, websites with a scrollbar within a content section is e.g. bad for mobile devices.
You may want to avoid this (or at least make different layouts, when a mobile device accesses your site)

you may want to work with this approach:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtm1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charsetUTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us" />
    <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />

    <meta name="MSSmartTagsPreventParsing" content="true" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />

    <title>Sample</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="web.css" />

    <style type="text/css" media="all">

        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        body {

            background-color: #eeeeee;
            font-family: arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: medium;

        }

        #container {

            width: 750px;
            margin: 0px auto;
            border: 1px dashed #000000;
            overflow: auto;

        }

        #header {

            height: 120px;
            background-color: gray;

        }

        #content {
            width: 390px;
            background-color: red;
            float: left;
            display: block;

        }


        #navigation {
            width: 180px;
            background-color: orange;
            float: left;
            display: block;

        }

        #news {
            width: 180px;
            background-color: blue;
            float: left;
            display: block;

        }

        #footer {
            clear: both;
            background-color: green;
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            header
        </div>

        <div id="navigation">
            navigation
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            content
        </div>

        <div id="news">
            news
        </div>


        <div id="footer">
            footer
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks. The article in the link I posted suggests that the content appear above the navigation rather than the bavigation above content. Sorry, I don't quite follow what you meant by `use the overflow: auto only on elements, which you actually WANT to have overflow auto`. What does it mean exactly i.e. how do i know which elements require an overfflow, why can't I use overflow to clear floats which has been suggested on numerous websites, etc?

Comment: its not a common praxis, how I learned this. You can use clear: both; instead.
user clear:both; on the element, that should clear the floating.
anyway, if you use width e.g., you even don't have to use clear:both, because, it wraps automatically when the space is filled up.

Comment: Thanks. The link of the article I posted suggest that the content div should appear above the navigation div. Not that it matters to me now but I didn't quite follow what you mean by `instead. user clear:both; on the element, that should clear the floating` what you meant by it exactly? Also I did specify a width and it didn't wrap automatically until I changed the structure of the document i.e. have the content div appear below the navigation div.